# Can I buy my domain again on another service

Tags: domains, godaddy

About a year ago GoDaddy had a $1 domain deal, so I got it. After a year it is time for it to auto-renew, $45??? No thanks, I will cancel and then buy on Crazy Domains, which is cheaper.

Can I do this? Will it be available for purchase as soon as it is unregistered?

GoDaddy sent an email saying the recovery fee is $80, but I thought that would not be an issue because I could just buy it again for cheaper? This makes me think that they hold on to it so you can only have that domain with them. On the other hand, I remember about backorder systems and think, wait that can't be the case?

What is the deal? Will I be able to purchase my domain with crazy domains once it expires with GoDaddy.

Comment: "Will it be available for purchase as soon as it is unregistered?" In general, without details about the TLD, the answer is no. It is not a good idea to operate like that, you should instead transfer the domain, but at least 2 months before expiration (ballpark figure to avoid problems).

Comment: I don't recommend Crazy domains, because I've seen they sometimes show any domain as available for registration even if it is registered by someone else. First check your domain is weather available on other domain registrar company or not.

Comment: @Goyllo Oh, I have not had that experience, but with godaddy, I have had in the past an issue where I go search for a domain and it says it not registered, then I refresh and it is. I visit the site and its one of those hyperlink pages, just holding the domain.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek transfer okay, hmm.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek turns out GoDaddy won't give me the EPP code for transfer, I'm guessing because it's expired, seems like a cash grab to me. Darn.

Comment: @RvBVakama majority of registrars charge between $10-20 in late grace period. So good luck moving your domain to another company that would do the exact same thing. Also NO domain registrar will give you a EPP code when you no longer own the domain... it's like expecting to 'MOVE' your mobile phone number from one network to another when you contract has ended and you've stopped your direct debts.Remember to check auto-renew next time.

Comment: @SimonHayter Check the fantastic answer from pbhj, it seems I'm entitled to get the EPP code to move even after expiry.

Comment: @RvBVakama you're entitled to get your EPP code at a cost, which is often the same additional fee applied to the renewal. On the ICANN website: [My domain name has **just** expired](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/domain-name-renewal-expiration-faqs-2018-12-07-en)  -> `This may result in an additional fee, sometimes referred to as a redemption fee.` which is exactly what I said since  late grace period is AKA the redemption grace period.

Comment: If you see the comments on pbjhs answer I did actually get my auth code, and at no cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you don't renew the domain they put it on offer then someone else can claim it. So in short they keep the domain on there service.(I could be wrong)

Answer (score 2):

They keep the domain for a certain period where no-one else can purchase it ("Auto-renew Grace Period" + "Redemption Grace Period"), but the past owner [ie you] can still recover the domain by paying a fee for renewal **and you can still transfer it** (see quote below). Then the domain is released for any registrar to purchase from the registry.

See this [ICANN infographic](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/gtld-lifecycle-2012-02-25-en):

[image: Lifecycle of a ggLTD from ICANN]

Now, registrars can reserve a domain without paying (or they could in the past), for a *short* period, then return them to the pool, so they can grab it and be the only registrar you can use, temporarily. **Once domains enter the pool proper you can't guarantee to win it**: the first buy order (which might be a squatter, competitor, someone with a back-order, ...) that ICANN process will take the domain; I'll say again you can't guarantee to win it.

**Back-order sites exist**, they attempt to be the first buy order that ICANN receive at the close of the delete period when the domain is released. I don't know, but I assume this is buy being close to ICANN's server (in network terms) and banging them with requests.

If you currently control the domain, and the domain is valuable to you, the easiest thing to do is renew it; then initiate a transfer in good time before your new renewal period ends. **However**, you can officially renew:

> You have the right to transfer an expired domain. Registrars are not allowed to deny a transfer due to expiration or non-renewal. (unless you haven't paid for a previous registration period). ([ICANN, point 4.](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/domain-name-renewal-expiration-faqs-2018-12-07-en))

Just don't expect the registrar you're leaving to be happy about doing it for you!

See also "[Expired domain deletion policy](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/registars/accreditation/eddp-en)".

Comment: Well it has expired and GoDaddy wont give me the auth key. I guess I will post in the godaddy forum

Comment: Can you give specific dates/details? When was the renewal due exactly? This might be your next avenue, https://forms.icann.org/en/resources/compliance/complaints/renewal/form. Or lawyer up, or hit twitter, or ...?

Comment: The expiry was 5 days ago, but it is still working? I wonder when they actually cut it off. Also, I just tried to get the auth code again and it worked now. I guess last night I guess the service was swamped or maintenance or something.
Lawyer up? Why would I do that? It's expensive. Also, I assume you are American and I heard everyone gets lawyers there for everything, but where I live that is not the case. Is that true?

Comment: Not from USA, but domains can have large values attached to them. If it was a case of a highly valuable domain then a lawyer could be relatively cheap; but I was saying it as a kind of joke. If the registrar won't respond and abide by ICANN's rules then they're possibly in breach of contract, forcing them to do what you want might need a lawyer but ICANN should be able to get a registrar to do what they need to. Glad you have things sorted.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Yeah if it was of high value it would be a good step to take, but also of it was enough to get a lawyer why would they be posting here, they probably have other people onhand who are more qualified for that. I'm just trying to get a good deal on my programming portfolio domain. :)